# sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods => install (LoadError)

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

Hi I got this error when run `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Can someone help, I am using MacOS 14.0 Sonoma